# How can I insert a value in the value attribute of a div with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I insert a value in the value attribute of a div using Internet Explorer 9. I tried a lot of JavaScript functions but I can only modify the content of the div, not the value attribute.

```
<div id="mydiv" value="somevalue">

</div>
```

This is my code that change the content not the value attribute.

```
var div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
div.innerHTML = "something";
```

Comment: 'value' attribute is not for a <div> maybe you want 'data-value' or something similar. All <div> possible attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

Comment: Yes but I should work on an existing code it's not my code ,created by other so I ask if this possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div.setAttribute('value', 'whateveryouwant');
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Answer (score 1):

`value` is not valid attribute of div, by using `setAttribute()` you can set any attribute to div which doesn't check if attribute is valid or not. `value` can be added for elements like `input` as below:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('myinput');
div.value="something";
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <input value="" id="myinput"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ,your solution is good but it's not my case I have to work with an existing code creation by others my div like : <div id="mydiv" value="somevalue">